# Duplicate Image Source to Another Image Tag More Than One Instance with a Single Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

Is there a way to apply a single function to an array of images which would duplicate an image's source from one img tag to another?

In the image example provided, I would like to have each image display with a duplicate image tag appearing right after, like so:

[image]

You can view a snippet below to refer to/edit the code I am currently working on to produce this.

```js
$('.pic > img').show(function() {
  var srcToCopy = $(this).attr('src');
  $('#imgsrc').attr('src', srcToCopy);
  console.log($('#imgsrc').attr('src'));
});
```

```css
.pic,
#imgsrc {
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Copy image 1 src: First instance -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://syedimranrocks.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/flower01low1.png">
  </div>
  <img id="imgsrc" />
</div>

<!-- Copy image 2 src: Second instance -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/Rose-Coral-Icon-906534.png">
  </div>
  <img id="imgsrc" />
</div>
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I realize that, but I need for the second img tag called per image to automatically extract/copy the src preceding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that ID's can't be duplicated in a page, they are unique by definition

Use  class instead and traverse to container and back to image instance within container you want to change.

There are multiple other ways to organize this same operation also within the container instance

```js
$('.pic > img').each(function() {
  var srcToCopy = $(this).attr('src');
  $(this).closest('.container').find('.imgsrc').attr('src', srcToCopy);
 
});
```

```css
.pic,
#imgsrc {
  display: inline-block;
}
img{width:60px}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Copy image 1 src: First instance -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="https://syedimranrocks.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/flower01low1.png">
  </div>
  <img class="imgsrc" />
</div>

<!-- Copy image 2 src: Second instance -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="pic">
    <img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/Rose-Coral-Icon-906534.png">
  </div>
  <img class="imgsrc" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly the type of solution I was looking for! Also, thanks for pointing out the ID issue, I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: This sort of pattern is extremely common for repeating components in a page. Store it in your memory bank. Could have done it other ways like `$(this).parent().next()` for example but going up to a main ancestor and using `find()` is really straightforward